# How to drag and drop paragraphs in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<title>Rearranging paragraphs</title>
<meta content="width=device-width">

</head>
<script>
function allowDrop(allowdropevent) 
{ 
    allowdropevent.target.style.color = 'blue';
    allowdropevent.preventDefault();
}

function drag(dragevent) 
{
    dragevent.dataTransfer.setData("text", dragevent.target.id);
    dragevent.target.style.color = 'green';
}

function drop(dropevent) 
{
    dropevent.preventDefault();
    var data = dropevent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    dropevent.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById("drag").style.color = 'black';
}
</script>
<body>
<div  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" contenteditable="true">
  <p id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" contenteditable="true">me toooo</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using above code to rearrange the paragraphs , but in chrome the content in different paragraphs drags selectively. Please help.

[image: These are the different paragraphs(example) under this div element which I want to rearrange using drag and drop.Now when I try to drag a single paragraph as one entity it doesn't move.This is the issue.]

These are the different paragraphs(example) under this div element which I want to rearrange using drag and drop.Now when I try to drag a single paragraph as one entity it doesn't move.This is the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want your parent div to be `contenteditable`? It may be causing the problems you have outlined. This is a good read on content editable and it's strengths and weaknesses: https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480#.inkv6iola

Comment: Yes , because I am trying to make a html editor

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please describe the issue you are having and what steps you've already taken to try to fix it.

Comment: have updated my question @AdamMazzarella

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're looking for but I don't believe this is the right forum for this. With that said, you may benefit from functionality similar to jQuery UI's [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) method. I do not think you should have nested divs that are both `contenteditable` because you'll end up running into strange problems with the way browsers handle this feature differently.

Comment: This is not the right forum for this ? @Adam Mazzarella

Comment: Is jQuery sortable along the lines of what you're looking for? I am still having trouble understanding what the end goal of your code is.

Comment: I have been given a task, that's it , even I am unable to fathom the goal.@Adam Mazzarella